# Try catch for ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, object, binary-search, linear-search

I am running a test for Binary search method for a value which is not found in an object array by using the try catch block, but the error `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is still being thrown.

Please refer to below code

```
int high = foodlist.length - 1;
int result = foodObj.binarySearch(foodlist, 0, high , key);

    try {
        if (result != -1)
            System.out.println("Element is found at index: " + result);
        else
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    } 
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Element not found!");
        System.out.println("Please enter an ID in the range of 1 to 3");
    }

    // Binary Search method
public static int binarySearch(Food[] foodlist, int low, int high, int value) {
    
    if (high >= low) {
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        
        if (foodlist[mid].id == value)
            return mid;
        
        else if (foodlist[mid].id > value)
            return binarySearch(foodlist, low, mid-1, value);
        else 
            return binarySearch(foodlist, high, mid+1, value);
    }
    return -1;
    
}
```

Maybe I should change the logic `return binarySearch(foodlist, high, mid+1, value);`, but I have tried all possible combination, same out of bound error is thrown or not found for valid elements is displayed.

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logical error in your code

**change this**

```
return binarySearch(foodlist, high, mid + 1, value);
```

**to this**

```
return binarySearch(foodlist, mid + 1, high, value);
```

Comment: thanks, I did the swapping and the code is catching the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Seems the problem is in your last `else` block. I guess it should be like:

```java
return binarySearch(foodlist, mid+1, high, value); // values passed as the low and high index are switched
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked... I had to change the order of mid+1 and high... great thanks again